# Passing Variables to a process python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Need help with how to modify/fix code to allow me to control what is occurring in a process. I have looked around and read I need to either make a global variable which the process can read or use an event function to trigger the process. Problem though is I don't know how to implement them in a class function. I thought that if I followed [pyimagesearch code](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/28/increasing-raspberry-pi-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) that it would work but it appears that it only works with the threading module and not the multiprocessing module.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from RPI.GPIO import LOW,OUT,HIGH,BCM
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self,PinOne=22,PinTwo=27):
        self.PinOne = PinOne
        self.PinTwo = PinTwo

        self.RunningSys = True

        GPIO.setmode(BCM)
        GPIO.setup(PinOne,OUT)
        GPIO.output(PinOne,LOW)
        GPIO.setup(PinTwo,OUT)
        GPIO.output(PinTwo,LOW)

   def Testloop(self):
        while self.RunningSys:
            GPIO.output(PinOne,HIGH)
            GPIO.output(PinTwo,HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(PinOne,LOW)
            GPIO.output(PinTwo,LOW)
        GPIO.output(PinOne,LOW)
        GPIO.output(PinTwo,LOW)

   def StopPr(self):
        self.RunningSys = False

   def MProc(self):
       MPGP = mp.process(target=TestClass().Testloop())
       MPGP.start()
       MPGP.join()
```

In a separate script

```
From testfile import TestClass
import time

TestClass().MProc()
time.sleep(4)
TestClass().StopPr()
```

Comment: I noticed that my current setup actually doesn't progress past the initial starting of the Process. Why? It doesn't make any sense as I'm starting a separate process

Comment: What is the reason to have a process inside a Class as a method? and why do you need a process for such simple task?

Comment: I'm starting off simple to make sure everything works before diving into the more complicated mess. At the end I will be pulling frames from the Raspberry pi camera, performing contour and center of mass calculations which will result in changes in the GPIO output. Ideally what the camera sees will affect what signals are sent out to an arduino

Comment: And the reason why I'm trying to wrap it into a class is because I will be attaching a GUI to it later. I thought a class object would be easier to manipulate with a GUI as the object would have been controlling a camera, analytics, an arduino, and data output.